# SCCM Powershell Script Package

Tags: powershell, command-line, configurationmanager, sccm

I have created a package in SCCM 2012 that should deploy and run a powershell script. I have looked at a previous post on here [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881090/powershell-script-not-running-properly-from-sccm) but there wasn't any information.

In the Program Command Line, I have the following command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -force -WindowStyle Hidden .\PowershellUpdateScript.ps1
```

I am targeting a test group and setting it to deploy immediately however when I check the deployment status, it shows as status "In Progress" and Description "Received". It has been that way for over 2 hours. I am not sure where the issue is.

I know that the Scripts feature is there and super convenient but the client powershell version needs to be a minimum version 3. The irony is that this package will update client powershell versions.

Any suggestions or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are updating the powershell version, instead of using a powershell script you should download the MS update package for the version of powershell.

You can then use the wusa.exe command to deploy the update.  Then use this ps command as a detection method

Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering -filter "HotFixID='KB#######'"